# How to animate addSubView: using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

**Setup**: have a `containerView` on screen inside a `UIViewController` (for the sake of simplicity let's say `containerView` takes up the whole screen).

**Problem**: create and add an `overlayView` as a subView to `containerView` and animate the appearance so that it would animate into position from the right as a response to a user action.

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.frame];
overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[containerView addSubview:overlayView]; // Can't add constraints before inserting into view hierarchy
```

**Approach**: tie the leading edge of the `overlayView` to the leading edge of the `containerView` with a constraint that I'll call `overlayLeadingConstraint`. Set `overlayLeadingConstraint.constant` to the width of `containerView` so that it would be initially positioned just off screen to the right.

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[overlayView(width)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[containerView addConstraints:constraints];
NSLayoutConstraint *overlayViewLeadingConstraint = [constraints objectAtIndex:0];
overlayViewLeadingConstraint.constant = containerView.frame.size.width;
// Height constraint not shown for simplicity
```

**Animation**: now onto the real problem; animate `overlayView` into position from the right. First approach is something like this:

```
overlayViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    [containerView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

But this does not work as all the code above would execute on the same run loop and so only the end result would be shown.

**Second approach**: try to defer the animation to a future run loop until after the initial layout after `addSubview:` has already taken place.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    overlayViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [containerView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
});
```

This does not work either and it hints that `addSubview:` and the setup of constraints can take up multiple run loops.

**Third approach**: try to delay the animation even further: several run loops into the future.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    overlayViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [containerView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}];
```

The time delay is small, but it allows several run loops to complete before the animation and this seems to achieve the desired effect.

**Questions:**
The above approach seems to be a workaround and not the *real* solution. So I'm wondering if there is a better approach to this. I have thought about using the hosting `viewController`'s `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method to get to know when `overlayView` is in place and it's ok to fire up the animation, but the documentation explicitly advises against this:

> However, this method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts 
>   of the view's subviews have been adjusted. Each subview is responsible for 
>   adjusting its own layout.

I'm starting to think that Apple's idea was to have all subViews added at initialization time and just hide those that you don't need immediately. So that when the time comes to animate a subView it would already be a member of the view hierarchy tied up properly with constraints.

How would you do it? Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing with some of the things you don't show, but this code, worked fine for me. I made a view in IB (containerView) that was 200 x 200, and used this code,

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIView *overlayView = [UIView new];
    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    overlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [containerView addSubview:overlayView];
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[overlayView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"overlayView":overlayView}];
    NSArray *constraints2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[overlayView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"overlayView":overlayView}];
    [containerView addConstraints:constraints];
    [containerView addConstraints:constraints2];
    NSLayoutConstraint *overlayViewLeadingConstraint = [constraints objectAtIndex:0];
    overlayViewLeadingConstraint.constant = containerView.frame.size.width;
    [containerView layoutIfNeeded];

    overlayViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [containerView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

This animated correctly. Notice that I put in a call to layoutIfNeeded before the animation block. That may or may not be necessary in your case, depending on some aspects of your code that you didn't show.

I don't know if using `[constraints objectAtIndex:0]` to get the constraint you want to modify is safe; it worked in this case, but I don't know if the order of the constraints set up with the visual format is guaranteed.

Comment: thanks for the input. That first call to `layoutIfNeeded` was the missing key to my problem. Interestingly, it makes so much sense now that you've showed it, but it just never came to my mind to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're right about the `objectAtIndex:` approach being unsafe. The visual format, however, conveys the idea better, so for the sake of the example it served my purposes better. I'll replace the visual format in the shipping version though.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added anything to the `animations` block that will animate. The `animations` block is generally considered to be the "I want my UI to end up in this state; animate stuff to make that happen" block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    overlayViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0.0;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, although I believe the recommended way is to modify the constraint first and than in the animation block simply call `layoutIfNeeded`. Putting the constant update inside the animation block would have the same effect but the call to `layoutIfNeeded` is what triggers the animation and so is missing from your example.

Comment: You are incorrect. As I stated, if you do not perform your value changes within the `animations` block, they will not be animated.

Comment: No, Ian, you are incorrect. I've done many animations putting the constraint change outside the animation block (but inside the same method that has the animateWithDuration call), and it works fine (and you do need to call layoutIfNeeded inside the animation block, as kadam pointed out).